# Не работают WordPress категории

Tags: wordpress

Есть страница блога, с сайдбаром в котором выводятся категории. По клику на категорию ничего не сортируется и выводятся все посты со всех категорий, просто игнорируя, но линк меняется на "website/categories/category-name". При переходе на "website/categories" выдает ошибку 404.

Пробовал менять постоянные ссылки и отключал Yoast Seo, не помогает.

Comment: Используй нормальную тему из оф каталога.

Comment: Судя по "website/categories/category-name" у Вас что-то не то с постоянными ссылками, потому что должно быть category, а не categories. Проверьте наличие шаблона category.php - он по умолчанию отвечает за вывод постов отдельной категории